# How to add login with amazon in my flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to add the login with amazon in my flutter app. And I need to read and writ the alexa skill.

Comment: [flutter_lwa](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lwa) A Flutter plugin for using Login with Amazon on Android and iOS

Comment: In that we can access the alexa skill read and write.

Comment: Not. It's only for Login with Amazon

Comment: I want that also. Can you suggest some other solution.

Comment: @GursewakSingh I tried with lwa, but while click on the login button my app is Lost connection to device. App is closing automatically.